# can a MP4 file contains more than one movie atom?

Tags: mp4

we know movie atom in a MP4 container file stores information that describes a movie's data. I am wondering if a single MP4 file can contain more than one movie atoms (atom type of 'moov')?

anyone knows? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A valid MP4 file may only contain one single 'moov' box. This is stated in 8.2.1 of the ISO 14496-12 specification:

> The metadata for a presentation is stored in the single Movie Box which occurs at the top-level of a file.
>   Normally this box is close to the beginning or end of the file, though this is not required.

If you are using fragmented MP4 files the role of the 'moov' is mostly played by 'moof' boxes and those typically exist multiple times.